# Linq List.Contains(x => ...) - CS0103 x does not exist in the current context (within foreach)

Tags: c#

I've got two simple Lists that I'm trying to synchronise.
`List<Guid> untrackedList` contains a bunch of Guids.
`List<Foo> trackedList` contains a number of objects `Foo` that have (amongst others) an ID property of Guid. This list is tracked by entity framework, so I'd like to add new items for those present in untrackedList that aren't already in trackedList, and remove everything from trackedList that isn't present in untracked List as well.

```
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    const int someThing = 1000;
    var untrackedList = new List<Guid>()
    {
        new Guid("8fcfb512-ca00-4463-b98a-ac890b3ac4da"),
        new Guid("6532b60b-f047-4a96-9e5f-c5a242f9a1f5"),
        new Guid("103cb7e4-1674-490c-b299-4b20d90e706c"),
        new Guid("6c933cce-fb0e-4e1b-bbc3-e62235933cc8")
    };
    var trackedList = new List<Foo>()
    {
        new Foo() { SomeId = new Guid("6532b60b-f047-4a96-9e5f-c5a242f9a1f5"), Something = someThing },
        new Foo() { SomeId = new Guid("12345678-abcd-1234-1234-1234567890ab"), Something = someThing }
    };
    // testing Find and Exists
    var testFind = trackedList.Find(x => x.SomeId == new Guid("6532b60b-f047-4a96-9e5f-c5a242f9a1f5")); // finds one Foo
    var testExists = trackedList.Exists(x => x.SomeId == new Guid("12345678-abcd-1234-1234-1234567890ab")); // == true

    foreach (var guid in untrackedList)
    {
        // add all items not yet in tracked List
        if (!trackedList.Exists(x => x.SomeId == guid))
        {
            trackedList.Add(new Foo() { SomeId = guid, Something = someThing });
        }
    }
    // now remove all from trackedList that are not also in untracked List (should remove 12345678-...)
    trackedList.RemoveAll(x=> !untrackedList.Contains(x.SomeId)); // successful, but also shows CS0103 in the debugger
}
```

This is probably not the most efficient way of doing it, but it appears to work. However, when running this through the debugger, I was thrown off by the error CS0103 "The name 'x' does not exist in the current context"
[image: Debugger Screenshot]

What causes this error? Why does it not result in an exception?

The same error is shown in the debugger on the .RemoveAll method (last line).

Comment: It looks like you have the mouse over the `SomeId` property - that can't be evaluated since `x` is not bound at that point.

Comment: i've tested the code, it runs fine on my machine. it may be what Lee said

Comment: I have also tested this code in my machine and its working as expected!

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to test and confirm this to be working. @Lee is probably correct; although I do not have the mouse there I suspect that ReSharper may continuously evaluate - potentially at a time when it is not bound. Again, thanks everyone!

Comment: @ExternalUse it is also working for me if i open `{` and close `}` the `MyTestMethod()`

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer Sorry, that was an oversight when constructing the simplified example. I'll amend the question to reflect this.

Comment: This same issue as had me pulling my hair out the last few hours. Glad I found this question.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, usually that error is occured when variable is not scope and can not be calculated, that is excaly what happens if compiler tries to calculate x, x is not really calculated at the scope of method MyTestMethod, there is an expression build from query and  caculated in different scope, because x is part of expression it is calculated in different scope.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. A suggestion: please refine your answer in grammar as well as structure. Your answer is one sentence over 4 lines...